# How to use an expression as loop counter in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm completely new in the Linux world, i-m using a Bash shell and practicing a bit.
How can i perform a loop giving as counter an expression?
For example looping through the amount of word in a file.

```
for n in(wc -w text.txt)
 do
   echo "word number $n"
 done
```

Unfortunately the above script its not working.
The only way i have found so far is to first print the value of wc -w text.txt, then assign it to a variable and then loop:

```
wc -w text.txt
a=10   //result saw by wc -w text.txt
for((b=0; b<a; b++))
do
echo "$b"
done
```

The problem is that i need to retrieve the value of wc -c and asssing it directly to a variable, in case i have to write a script that runs automatically, the problem is that

```
a= wc -w test.txt
```

Will not work,

Any advice?

Comment: `a=wc -w test.txt` should be in backticks or `$()` to work and no space around `=`, i.e. `a=$(wc -w test.txt)`

Comment: a=$(wc -c test.txt) or a=$\`wc -c test.txt\`  will assign to a a text value: '6 test.txt', if you try to iterate this value, you of course then will get an error (arithmetic expression needed)

Comment: Use `a=$(wc -w < test.txt)` to remove the filename in `wc` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way to do this is

```
tmp=$(wc -w <text.txt)
for ((i=0; i<$tmp; i++))
do 
    echo $i; 
done
```

The `<text.txt` part is necessary, because normally, the output of the `wc` command is

```
wordcount1  INPUTFILE1
wordcount2  INPUTFILE2
...
```

The max value for `i` must equal the word count of your file, so you must take away the `INPUTFILE1` part before your loop works as intended. Using an input stream `<` rather than a filename takes care of this issue.

Using a temp variable prevents `wc` from being called on each iteration.

Comment: (set -v; your code) shows that wc is called for each iteration; use a variable instead

Comment: Thanks! added your suggestions to the answer.

Comment: is the dollar sign in this case used as indicator for an expression evaluation?

Comment: @JBoy Yes, the `$(...)` notation works the same as backquoting in bash